# storing an input value in the localstorage and reuse it in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have written this code where I get the value from an input and Im trying to store that value in the localStorage so that the browser remembers the value and display the right color scheme. However it does not work, do I need to write more code to store/re-use keys in the localstorage?

```
<select id="colorScheme" name="colorMode"> 
        <option value="light">Light Mode</option>
        <option value="dark">Dark Mode</option>
        </select>
```

```
const colorScheme = document.querySelector("#colorScheme").value;
    localStorage.setItem("colorScheme", colorScheme);

    if (localStorage.getItem("colorScheme") == "light") {
        console.log("light");
        initLightMode();
    } else if (localStorage.getItem("colorScheme") == "dark") {
        console.log("dark");
        initDarkMode();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it that way javascript will store the current color scheme in the localstorage before retrieving the old value; to prevent it from happening you should consider adding event listeners, like this:

```
const selector = document.querySelector("#colorScheme");
// we add an event listener that will trigger each time the selector 
// content will be updated 
selector.addEventListener("change", (val) => {
  const colorScheme = selector.value;
  console.log("Set colorScheme to: " + colorScheme);
// we store the new value in the localstorage 
  localStorage.setItem("colorScheme", colorScheme);
});
// here we need another event listener that will trigger 
// when the page loads: what this does is loading the value
// from localstorage into the selector 
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  //we read from the localStorage the old value:

  let colorScheme = localStorage.getItem("colorScheme");
  selector.value = colorScheme;

  if (colorScheme == "light") {
      console.log("light");
      initLightMode();
  } else if (colorScheme == "dark") {
      console.log("dark");
      initDarkMode();
  }
});
```

Comment: Will this save the value even if browser is closed/refreshed

Comment: Yes, the value will remain even after closing and refreshing!